# printf with %s to include null characters

Tags: c, string, printf

I need to concatenate some strings, and I need to include NULL bytes. I don't want to treat a '\0' as a terminating byte. I want to save my valuable NULL bytes!

In a code example, if

```
    char *a = "\0hey\0\0";
```

I need to printf in a format that will output "\0hey\0\0".

-AUstin

Comment: How are you going to work out how long the string is?

Comment: its predetermined. i have allocated space, say 8 bytes. i want to smack together a few strings of various, given sizes, using a printf(%s%s%s...)

Comment: If the array has embedded nulls it is not a string. Do not call it a string. Call it an array of (unsigned) char (with embedded nulls). As it isn't a string you cannot reliably use any *string function* on that object: no `"%s"` conversion to `printf` (or `scanf`), no `fputs`, no `fgets`, no `strcpy`, no `strcat`, ...

Answer (score 13):

How about:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%c", a[i]);
```

If you want a 'printf-like' function to use this when you specify `%s` in a format string you could include the above code in your own function. But as @Neil mentioned, you'll struggle finding an alternative to looking for null bytes to determine the length of strings. For that I guess you could use some kind of escape character.

Comment: Why would it take lots of code? It's a trivial for loop? It's hard to see an alternative to this.

Comment: i say lots of code because to do this for 10 strings means 10 for-loops. not the end of the world of course. it just seems less ideal, however i admit im not working with the most ideal situation

Comment: @austin - Does it not mean one function and ten calls?

Comment: I recommend using putchar() instead of printf()'s for this. Characters don't need to be formatted, so putchar() is a lot more efficient.

Comment: Or how about [`fwrite(a, 1, 4, stdout);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite).  That's even better than `putchar`; you don't need to loop over the bytes one at a time at all.

Answer (score 8):

The issue here is that the length of the string `a` cannot be easily determined.  For example, your code..

```
char *a = "\0hey\0\0";
```

.. allocates seven bytes to the string, the last being the NULL terminator.  Using a function like `strlen` would return 0.

If you know the precise length of the string, then you can write or iterate over the bytes thus:

```
#ifdef ESCAPE_NULLS
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        if (a[i] == 0)
            printf("\\0");
        else
            printf("%c", a[i]);
#else
    write(1, a, 6);
#endif
```

But you have to know about the 6.

The alternative is not to use NULL-terminated strings, and instead implement an alternative storage mechanism for your bytes; for example a length-encoded array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int length;
    char *bytes;
} bytearr;

void my_printf(bytearr *arr)
{
    #ifdef ESCAPE_NULLS
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= arr->length; i++)
            if (arr->bytes[i] == 0)
                printf("\\0");
            else
                printf("%c", arr->bytes[i]);
    #else
        write(1, arr->bytes, arr->length);
    #endif
}

void main(void)
{
    bytearr foo = {
        6, "\0hey\0\0"
    };
    my_printf(&foo);
}
```

Graceless, but hopefully you get the idea.

**Edit: 2011-05-31**

Rereading the question I just noticed the word "concatenate".  If the NULL characters are to be copied faithfully from one place in memory to another (not backslash-escape), and you know the total number of bytes in each array beforehand, then you can simply use [`memcpy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy).

```
#include <string.h>
char *a = "\0hey\0\0";   /*  6 */
char *b = "word\0up yo"; /* 10 */
char *c = "\0\0\0\0";    /*  4 */
void main(void)
{
    char z[20];
    char *zp = z;
    zp = memcpy(zp, a, 6);
    zp = memcpy(zp, b, 10);
    zp = memcpy(zp, c, 4);
    /* now z contains all 20 bytes, including 8 NULLs */
}
```

Comment: you have an if/else statement in the first part of your response. does this imply that a printf("%c") on a NULL byte will not work?

Comment: It depends if you want to faithfully pass the null byte through to STDOUT, or backslash-escape it (which was how I read the original question).

Comment: @MattyK : Shouldn’t`write(1, a, 6);`be`write(1, a, sizeof(char)*6);`?

Comment: Sure, if you're writing proper, portable code. It's easy to be lazy and assume `sizeof(char)==1`

Comment: Don't mix POSIX `write()` with stdio `printf`.  Use `fwrite`.  And don't use `printf("%c"` for singe bytes, use `putchar`!  Or better, search for the next `0` and use `fwrite` for all the non-zero bytes with one function call.  Or copy-and-escape into a local buffer and fwrite that.  And BTW, `memcpy` isn't `strcat`: `memcpy` returns its first arg unmodified, not the *end* of where it wrote.  So your update repeatedly overwrites the start of `z`.  But yes, memcpy is the right tool for the job, if you use the right destination pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *a="\0hey\0\0";
int alen = 7;

char buf[20] = {0};
int bufSize = 20;

int i=0;
int j=0;
while( i<bufSize && j<alen )
{
    if(a[j]=='\0') {
        buf[i++]='\\';
        buf[i++]='0';
        j++;
    }
    else {
        buf[i++] = a[j++];
    }
}

printf(buf);
```