# Search inside a string that contains a new line?

Tags: c

I am using this :

```
  if(strstr(inData, respond) != NULL)
```

to search for the string `CMD` inside `inData` .

problem is that when new data looks like this :

```
Reboot
CMD
```

`strstr` will not find it, because it stops searching where is a new line.
Is there an elegant way (**not** using fancy functions since I can't) to get over it ?

Comment: `strstr` can find newline(include). There is an illegal character in front of the `CMD`. (maybe `'\0'`)

Comment: Thanks, how I don't see it ? what I show here is the inData print.

Comment: hex dump `inData`.

Comment: I agree with @BLUEPIXY, `strstr()` treats newlines like any other character. However, I would also expand your debugging to `respond` as well. Are you sure `respond` points to the characters `C`, `M`, `D`, `\0`? If `respond` contains a newline, or does not contain a NUL delimiter (`\0`), `strstr()` will similarly fail.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am loosing my mind with it, I guess there is something I can not see even if I hex dump it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, strstr does not stop at newline boundaries, but only at string terminators (\0)

Here is the relevant section from the man page:

> DESCRIPTION
>          The strstr() function finds the first occurrence of the substring    needle in the string haystack.  The terminating null
>   bytes
>          ('\0') are not compared.

So the assumption is, that there are null bytes within one of CMD or inData.
You should investigate the string inData and CMD in [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093660/printf-with-s-to-include-null-characters) or [hexdump it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775991/how-to-get-hexdump-of-a-structure-data) (as suggested by @BLUEPIXY)